# Print just coordinates

Tags: shapely, fiona

I am relatively new to coding, but I am using fiona within python and would like to print the coordinates that make up the points of the polygon to later add to a separate list. However I am having a hard time printing just the coordinates, I do not wish to print the id, type, properties etc... My current code prints the points as well as the type, I would like it to print without the type. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
output_polygons = []  
with fiona.open(input_shp) as polygons:  
    for polygon in polygons:  
        polygon['geometry']['coordinates'][0]  
        output_polygons.append(polygon)  
        pprint.pprint(polygon['geometry'])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try 
print polygon['geometry']['coordinates']
instead of
pprint.pprint(polygon['geometry'])